# Windows Crash Reporting

Tags: windows, crash, event-viewer, bsod

Not sure if this is the place to ask for this kind of help... but I've recently been having issues with my PC randomly shutting off at night (idle) and sometimes while in use.

Monitors+USB devices all power down
Motherboard Lights + CPU Fan Lights Stay On
Have to cycle power to fix.

This is generally at least a once a day occurrence, sometimes multiple times.

Things tried;

Reapplying thermal compound on both CPU + GPU
Replaced Motherboard

I have not tried replacing GPU/CPU yet as thats like... last ditch as I don't want to spend any money I don't need to.

Last failure

[Failure - Event Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VCEi.png)

Not sure if this helps or anything but just trying to get an idea of whats going on.

Please note: This particular crash was a BSOD whereas most of the time it simply just blacks out without anything.

Answer (score 0):

is it plugged into a power strip?

if it is that might be the problem, my pc was doing somthing close to that (though it was never a BSOD), and it was pluged into a power strip.

its that or it could be a fault of some sort.
it could be a windows issue, if you have the install disc, try re-installing windows, that could help...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention!

I have also reinstalled Windows at least twice, each time using a new SSD. Problem persisted through that process. It is on a Power Strip so I'll swap that out and see how that goes.